# RelationNotFoundException Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relation

I'm facing a problem, as to why the relation is not getting connected.

vendor.php

```
class Vendor extends Model
{
    public function internets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Internet');
    }
}
```

internets.php

```
class Internet extends Model
{
    protected $with=['vendor','coba'];
    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongTo('App\Vendor');
    }
}
```

any one can help me?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: please show your db structure

Comment: in your controller add `use App\Internet;` and/or `use App\Vendor;`

Answer (score 2):

it will be belongsTo

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendor');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

In your vendor

```
 class Vendor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Vendor Table Name';
    protected $primarykey = 'Your Vendor Table primary Key';
    public function internets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Internet::class, 'relational key');
    }
}
```

And In your internet

```
class Internet extends Model
{
    protected $with=['vendor','coba'];
    protected $table = 'Internet Table Name';
    protected $primarykey = 'Internet table primary key';
    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Vendor::class, 'relation key');
    }
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem let me know if this do the trick

Comment: Hi @Mohsin..I already added like this  protected $primarykey = 'id';
  public function Internet()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(App/Vendor::class,'vendor_id');
  }
I still get "null"